# Matrix differentials

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization

My goal is to minimise:

$$\min_w\left( w'(a \cdot\mathrm{diag}(1/|w_1|,...,1/|w_n|+ X)w+b'w+x'w\right)$$

where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ semi-positive definite, $b,w,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a>0$. Also, $w_1,...,w_n\neq 0$. I am having trouble with the following expression:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(w'(a\cdot \mathrm{diag}(1/|w_1|,...,1/|w_n|+ X)w\right)$$

I am aware that $w'Aw=2A$, if $A=A'$. In the above case $A$ is a function of $w$, so I am not sure how to go about this. Could anyone explain to me please, how to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
and define the vectors 
$$\eqalign{
c &= b + x,\quad
s &= {\rm sign}(w) \cr
}$$
and the matrices
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm Diag}(s),\quad
W &= {\rm Diag}(w) \cr
}$$
as well as the scalar $\alpha = a$

The following relationships will prove useful.
$$\eqalign{
SW &= WS = {\rm abs}(W) \cr
W1 &= w \implies W^{-1}w=1  \cr
S1 &= s \implies S^{-1}s=1  \cr
A\!:\!B &= B\!:\!A = A^T\!:\!B^T \cr
A\!:\!BC &= AC^T\!:\!B = B^TA\!:\!C \cr
\cr
}$$
Write the cost function in terms of these new variables.
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= \alpha SW^{-1}:ww^T + X:ww^T + c:w \cr
 &= \alpha SW^{-1}w:w + X:ww^T + c:w \cr
 &= \alpha S1:w + X:ww^T + c:w \cr
 &= (\alpha s+c):w + X:ww^T \cr
}$$
Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= (\alpha s+c):dw + X:(dw\,w^T+w\,dw^T) \cr
 &= (\alpha s + c + Xw + X^Tw):dw \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w}
 &= \alpha s + c + Xw + X^Tw \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be much simpler than this. So, can I say:$$0=as+c+(X+X')w\implies w=-(as+c)(X+X')^{-1}$$ assuming that $X$ is invertible.

Comment: Since the vector $s$ is a function of $w$, i.e. $\,\,s={\rm sign}(w)$ you cannot obtain a closed-form solution. But you can setup an iterative solution $$w_{k+1} = (X^T+X)^{-1}(\alpha\,{\rm sign}(w_k) + c)$$

Comment: To initialize the iteration, try $\,w_0 = c\,$ or perhaps $\,w_0 = 1.$